# Getting LP relaxation before SCIPsolve

Tags: scip

I would like to use the LP relaxation of the problem *before* calling `SCIPsolve()` and I would like to know what is the best/simplest way of doing this.

I'm currently creating a `SCIP_LPI` that I would like to populate with my original problem's data. I thought that a simple way would be to call `SCIPgetLPI()` (and then copy everything), but when I write that problem to file (to see it) I get an empty problem. I guess this is because since I haven't called `SCIPsolve()` yet. I even tried calling `SCIPpresolve()` first, but the problem is still empty.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain what you want to do? I am not quite sure if writing an own lpi is the correct way to handle things but this depends on your intention.

Answer (score 1):

To get the LP relaxation I believe you will have to call `SCIPsolve` at some point. One way I see to do this and that does use `SCIPsolve` is to set the parameter `limits/nodes` to 1, call `SCIPsolve`, which will only solve the root node. Then you can set `limits/nodes` to -1 and call `SCIPsolve` again to solve completely if needed. Note that doing so will give you the LP relaxation of the presolved problem, and cuts will be added. Depending on what you would like to do, you may want to disable presolving and cuts.